# Prettify stringified object in javascript to serve in a static html page

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I'm trying to use this code to prettify a JSON object retrieved from another service and return it in a static page (has to be).

The javascript functions work but I'm having issues dealing with the stringified object.

It works fine encoding for example before the return statement for the html

```
json = "{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}"
```

and not using stringify but it does not using JSON.stringify with a real JSON object instead.

```
function getStaticResponse(jsonObjectRetrieved){

 return '<html>'
            + '<head>'
                + '<title>' + 'title' + '</title>'
                + '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'
                    + '/something' + '">'
            + '</head>'

             + '<body>'
              + '<pre class="json-output box bg-color-weight-6 font-calibri">'
              + jsonFormat(JSON.stringify(jsonObjectRetrieved))
              + '</pre>'
            + '</body>'

         + '</html>';
}

function transformJson(k, v) {
  if (k === 'href' && typeof v === 'string') {
      var label = v.replace(/&/gi, '&amp;');
    return '<a href=' + v + '>' + label + '</a>';
  }
  return v;
}

function jsonFormat(jsonString) {
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString, transformJson);
    return JSON.stringify(jsonObj, undefined, 2)
            .replace(/\s"(\w*)":/g, ' "<span class="key">$1</span>":')
            .replace(/:\s"(.*)"/g, ': "<span class="string">$1</span>"');
};
```

Many thanks

Comment: Try checking for syntax errors at quotes of returned string at `getStaticResponse`

Comment: It works but displays all the json on a single line instead of prettify it (with links and styles)

Comment: not understanding the problem or expected results. Create demo that includes expected results

Comment: Is `key` , `string` defined at `jsonFormat` ?

Comment: Note that where you have `undefined` argument can be a `replacer` function  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: yes classnames are correctly defined

Comment: Lost half hour on nothing. The problem was just the json not being json but a string and thus being escaped again by JSON.stringify. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing call to `JSON.stringify` at `jsonFormat(JSON.stringify(jsonObjectRetrieved))`

```js
var json = "{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}";

function getStaticResponse(title, jsonObjectRetrieved) {

  return '<html>' 
         + '<head>' 
         + '<title>' + title + '</title>' 
         + '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' 
         + 123 + '">' 
         + '</head>'
         + '<body>' 
         + '<pre class="json-output box bg-color-weight-6 font-calibri">' 
         + jsonFormat(jsonObjectRetrieved) 
         + '</pre>' 
         + '</body>'
         + '</html>';
}

function transformJson(k, v) {
  if (k === 'href' && typeof v === 'string') {
    var label = v.replace(/&/gi, '&amp;');
    return '<a href=' + v + '>' + label + '</a>';
  }
  return v;
}

function jsonFormat(jsonString) {
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString, transformJson);
  return JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, 2)
    .replace(/\s"(\w*)":/g, ' "<span class="key">$1</span>":')
    .replace(/:\s"(.*)"/g, ': "<span class="string">$1</span>"');
};

document.write(getStaticResponse("abc", json));
```

Comment: yep, this is the answer since the argument "jsonObjectRetrieved" passed in in my case was not actually an object but a string.